# Does a kafka consumer machine need to run zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

So my question is this: If i have a server running Kafka (And zookeeper), and another machine only consuming messages, does the consumer machine need to run zookeeper too? Or does the server take care of all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Role of Zookeeper in Kafka is:

- **Broker registration:** (cluster membership) with heartbeats mechanism to keep the list current
- **Storing topic configuration:**  which topics exist, how many partitions each
  has, where are the replicas, who is the preferred leader, list of ISR for
  partitions
- **Electing controller:** The controller is one of the brokers and is responsible for maintaining the leader/follower relationship for all the partitions.

So Zookeeper is required only for kafka broker. There is no need to have Zookeper on the producer or consumer side.

Comment: This isn't completely true

Answer (score 1):

The consumer does not need zookeeper

Comment: Thank you very much good sir. On the other hand, would a producer need zookeeper?

Comment: No. Zookeeper is only needed by Kafka brokers. No need for it on the producer and consumer side.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned which version of Kafka or the clients you're using.

Kafka consumers using 0.8 store their offsets in Zookeeper, so it is required for them. However, no, you would not run Zookeeper and consumers on the same server

From 0.9 and later, clients are separate from needing it (unless you want to manage external connections to Zookeeper on your own for storing data)